# Cannot connect using Firefox?

Tags: help

Every time I try using Tor. An error message reads "Firefox cannot establish connection to server", I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help?

See screenshot.[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or some more detail about what you're doing and what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

According to the onion address from your screenshot the address http://atlantisrky4es5q.onion is down. A [search](https://ahmia.fi/search/?q=atlantisrky4es5q.onion) at [ahmia.fi (Hidden Service search)](https://ahmia.fi/) shows some mentions of this address, but the market itself is offline for quite some time.